# c# inheritance override method parameter with a descendant class

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, covariance

I've tried to generalize this question so that it is still meaningful and yet doesn't have all the code of my actual classes.  Basically, what I would like to do is have a method in a derived class override one of it's ancestors methods but use a parameter that is derived from the class that is a parameter in the ancestor's method signature.  Hopefully this code explains it better:

```
public abstract class BaseShape
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public abstract bool Modified();

    public abstract void Validate(List<string> errors);
}

public class DescendantShape : BaseShape
{
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }

    public override bool Modified()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void Validate(List<string> errors)
    {
        //
    }
}

public abstract class BaseVehicle
{
    public void SaveChanges(BaseShape shape)
    {
        if (!shape.Modified()) return;
        var errorList = new List<string>();
        shape.Validate(errorList);
        if (errorList.Count > 0)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in errorList)
            {
                sb.Append(s + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
        }

        WriteToStorage(shape);

        if (!shape.Active)
            MarkInactive(ref shape);
    }

    public abstract void WriteToStorage(BaseShape shape);

    public abstract void MarkInactive(ref BaseShape shape);
}

public class DescendantVehicle : BaseVehicle
{
    public override void WriteToStorage(DescendantShape shape)
    {
        //
    }

    public override void MarkInactive(ref DescendantShape shape)
    {
        shape = null;
    }
}
```

I don't want to have to repeat the code in the SaveChanges method for all of BaseVehicle's descendants; however, all of BaseVehicle's descendants will be using differnet descendants of BaseShape.  The code above of course will not build and while I understand why (or at least think I do), I've been scratching my head all morning trying to figure out how to properly design it.

Comment: What errors are you encountering when you compile this code?

Comment: Not in C#. What you are looking for called [contravariant method arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Contravariant_method_argument_type). There probably answer about it by Eric Lippert somewhere...

Comment: What would you expect to happen if I called `new DescendantVehicle.WriteToStorage(new SomeOtherShape())`? Basically, C# doesn't directly support what you're trying to achieve, but you might want to consider using generics.

Comment: To add to @JonSkeet's comment - if you add your actual goal there may be other approaches that are within C# and type safe.

Comment: You could keep the descendants parameter as `BaseShape` itself and add a cast inside the method or take a look at [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish what you are after by updating your vehicle classes as so:

```
public abstract class BaseVehicle<T> where T : BaseShape
{
    public void SaveChanges(T shape)
    {
        if (!shape.Modified()) return;
        var errorList = new List<string>();
        shape.Validate(errorList);
        if (errorList.Count > 0)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in errorList)
            {
                sb.Append(s + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
        }

        WriteToStorage(shape);

        if (!shape.Active)
            MarkInactive(ref shape);
    }

    public abstract void WriteToStorage(T shape);

    public abstract void MarkInactive(ref T shape);
}

public class DescendantVehicle : BaseVehicle<DescendantShape>
{
    public override void WriteToStorage(DescendantShape shape)
    {
        //
    }

    public override void MarkInactive(ref DescendantShape shape)
    {
        shape = null;
    }
}
```

This is a solution implementing [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) as mentioned by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Wow that was fast!  Thanks.